# Given a smooth curve, ODE problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My problem is the following:
Given a smooth curve $x=\alpha(t)$,$y=\beta(t)$,$a<t<b$suppose $a<a'<b'<b$.Prove that: The interval $a'\leq t\leq b'$ is the union of a finite number of closed intervals on each of which the curve is a graph of the form $y=\phi(x)$ or $x=\delta(y)$ with continuously differentiable $\phi$ and $\delta$. 
Can you help me in this problem with a suggestion or solution? Thanks for your attention. :)

Comment: This is not true in general, for example, your assumptions don't prevent the curve from intersecting itself in the $xy$ plane which means that $x$ and $y$ can't be solved for in terms of each other uniquely.

Comment: @Km356 If you restrict to a small enough interval, you don't have to worry about self-intersections. You just make the interval so small that it doesn't include both $t$-values which correspond to the intersection point.

Comment: I think it depends on what exactly he means by smooth. It seems to me that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be one to one. So if by "smooth" he means that both functions have continuous non-zero derivatives on the interval, then what you say is true, If that's not what you mean, then I'm surely overlooking something.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. A curve ```x=\alpha(t),y=\beta(t),a<t<b``` is said to be smooth if ```\alpha``` and ```\beta``` are both continuously differentiable and if ```(\alpha'(t))^{2}+(\beta'(t))^{2}\sqsupset 0```

Comment: Write your code between "$"s